# String Length Attribute

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, attributes

I have this class:

```
public class TranslationItem : CmsDto
{
    [Required(LocalizationManager.Guid, ErrorMessage = LocalizationManager.Validation_Required)]
    public string FirstField
    {
        get { return GetValue(() => FirstField); }
        set { SetPropertyValue(value); }
    }

    [Required(LocalizationManager.Guid, ErrorMessage = LocalizationManager.Validation_Required)]
    public string SecondField
    {
        get { return GetValue(() => SecondField); }
        set { SetPropertyValue(value); }           
    }
}
```

It used to create two-way binding for localizations for my entities.

Properties First and Second Field have required attribute and must have String Length attribute.

```
public ObservableCollection<TranslationItem> PairValues
    {
        get { return _pairValues; }
        private set { SetProperty(ref _pairValues, value); }
    }
```

Property in my VM.

My question is: Can I create custom String Length Attribute with dynamic max length value?

For example, have 2 PairValues Collection's in my VM, but first has 255 and 500 (first and second field) and second has 255 and 255?

Anyway, I need to have ability to choose any string length in xaml or VM for every use in my project.

Comment: Make an object that has the max length as a property.

Comment: For now I have two windows using this collection. By your idea i need create two classes with different string length. If I will have 10 windows? 10 classes?

Comment: make a static class that holds the collection. somewhat spaghetti and not thread safe but still.